# F5/Continue to next request

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, debugging

While debugging in ASP.NET Core w/ VS 2019, when I have [break on exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) turned on , I break on the throwing, which is what I want , but then I have to continue, <kbd>F5</kbd> through each pop of the stack .

how do I say "CONTINUE out of this request & let the exception bubble up to the top w/o breaking"?  is that an option in VS?

---

[image: screenshot of the call stack]

Comment: I've requested this feature on numerous VS feedback forms. It's very time-consuming to press F5 to bubble exceptions up to the web-api controller every time an exception occurs deep down in the call-stack on the server while debugging from a SPA. I've found the easiest solution is to stop debugging and re-attach the debugger. It's actually easier than pressing F5 10+ times. Why not add a short-cut key instead. ALT+F5, for instance. Request this from the VS team!

Comment: got a link for the VS feedback forum?  happy to upvote!  @Frode

Comment: I've mentioned it in those feedback forms that pops up in Visual Studio once in a while. I just made a suggestion at the developer-community (I copied your topic [F5/Continue to next request]. Upvote the suggestion here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Debugger---F5Continue-to-next-request/10356798

Answer (score 1):

As the ASP.NET Core app is a long-running process, VS has no way of knowing where & when a request starts and ends. You can disable all breakpoints, hit F5, then re-enable them for the next request.

- Use the top menu: **Debug** > **Disable All Breakpoints**
- Use [Breakpoints panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Specify_advanced_properties_of_a_breakpoint_)

You always can set a hotkey to speed up this workflow

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that what you're seeing is the exception being rethrown on every async stack frame. You could confirm this if the exception dialog says that you can suppress the exception when thrown from System.Private.CoreLib.dll assembly, even though it was originally thrown in your code.

[image: Application exception rethrown from System.Private.CoreLib]

If you disable Just My Code, you should see that the exception is thrown from ExceptionDispatchInfo, which is the type used to rethrow exceptions with their original call stack in async/await. This is also what causes these exceptions to be thrown from System.Private.CoreLib.dll.

[image: Call stack of rethrown exception including ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw]

The only way I have found to improve this is to not break when the exception is thrown from System, either by using exception filter with module parameter, or in exception dialog > Exception Settings. This is only valid for exceptions that you never encounter from System.Private.CoreLib.dll. I am also not sure how this would work for Just My Code and external libraries as an exception might reach your code only after redispatch from async/await machinery.

With that in mind, you'll often just have to F5 all the way or rely more on breakpoints instead of exceptions for debugging.

Alternatively, as hinted in the other answer, you could disable exceptions until the request completes and re-enable them.